# Custom Firebase Performance Monitoring

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I am working on an Android studio project and have integrated "Firebase Performance Monitoring". I have tracked the api from the user and got the results. How can I add additional properties to filter results in statistics like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase performance has "Custom Attributes" precisely for this reason. It allows you to add attributes to all the traces that can enable you to slice and dice the data like you mentioned.

There are some attributes that are automatically added to every trace (No code required): https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon#attributes

For your custom use cases, you can add custom attributes as needed. APIs are available at https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom-attributes

Unfortunately, custom attributes are not available on Out of the box collected metrics.

Comment: Thank you I have a question whether the session number is the parameter representing that request api

Comment: Can you clarify which session you are referring to? Firebase performance has a feature named “sessions” which has no relation with with the request API. It just refers to the feature which provides more detailed information about a particular session of the app providing details about CPU/Memory and other activity details during the session.

Comment: That's great, but I feel firebase performance is misrepresenting the number of user network requests API on my app .Is it possible for statistical data to be affected by the time zone difference in my country?.Firebase performance has an "sample" feature . what the parameter means? @Visu